# Android firebase firestore&functions pushNotification using fcm token error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been working on firebase functions for whole day after upgrading the project,
what I want is to pushNotification to the token of the firestore document users,

This is my db structure

EX: when the collection Visitor doc change,push message to the token inside the doc
[image][image]

```
exports.vsUp = functions.firestore.document("Visitor/{docId}").onUpdate(
    (snapshot, context) => {
        admin.firestore().collection("Visitor/{docId}/{token}/{docId}").get().then(
            result => {
                var registrationTokens = [];
                result.docs.forEach(
                    tokenDocument => {
                        registrationTokens.push(tokenDocument.data().token);
                    }
                );
                admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
                    tokens: registrationTokens,
                    notification: {
                        title: snapshot.data().visitor_name,
                        body: snapshot.data().visitor_status
                    }
                })
            }
        )
    }
```

This is my functions.js code right now,and it is not working,

How can a acheive what I want to do?
Thanks>3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line won't work:

```
admin.firestore().collection("Visitor/{docId}/{token}/{docId}").get()
```

The `{token}` bits in here are just interpreted as literal strings. And since there's no collection/document with that name, you get no results.

If you want to load all tokens for the user that is indicated in the request, it'd look something like this:

```
admin.firestore().collection(`Visitor/${context.params.docId}/token`).get()
```

So you can see that:

- This uses `` ` `` to mark the string, so that it's interpreted as a template by JavaScript. You don't need to do that on the first line, as that one is interpreted by Firebase itself when you deploy the Cloud Function.
- The path now consists of three parts, so that it points to a collection, instead of the four in your code, which means it points to a document.
- We use `${context.params.docId}` to get the value of `docId` that triggered our Cloud Function.

Note that there may be many more reasons why messages are not delivered to the device, but these were definitely some of the reasons why your code was not reading anything from Firestore.

Comment: I tried some simple functions,but found out it couldnt send any message using token,

Comment: it showed Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous>

Comment: Unhandled rejection

Comment: Yeah, as said: there may be more problems with your code, and definitely also reasons outside your code why you may not receive the notifications. These were just the first ones that jumped out at me.

Comment: thanks i will discover more document about this